Cambiar color de fondo a través de botón con JS
Estuve probando crear un botón que cambie su color de fondo cada vez que se hace clic en él, pero parece que mi código no está funcionando.
Este es mi código:


<button onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]">Clic</button>




¿Cuál es la idea de [Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]? Y por cierto: se desaconseja usar manejadores de eventos inline. Usa el evento click de JS.

Tu codigo es correcta y funciona correctamente, cual es el problema?

Deberías multiplicar por 3, los arrays de JavaScript comienzan en cero y Math.random() devuelve un número entre 0 y 1 (incluidos)

De la forma en la cual tienes definida la funcionalidad del botón, en ocasiones te entregará el mismo color cada que des clic.
Si lo que deseas es que se muestre un color diferente cada que des clic, puedes iterar sobre el array de colores definiendo una variable indice que cambiará de valor cada vez que des clic


//* Define variable para índice y array de colores
var myIndex = 0;
var array = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'];
<button onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = array[myIndex]; myIndex = (myIndex + 1)%array.length;">Clic</button>



